# MVC4-WCF - async loading of data from 3rd party

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, wcf, iis

I'm setting up a server-client solution with ASP.NET MVC4 and a WCF-service, and was thinking you might have some input to a couple of questions.

The WCF-service get its data from a 3rd-party service which is quite slow. So my plan is the following scenario:

1. User logs in, setting off a jQuery-ajax-request to the MVC-controller
2. The Controller requests the WCF-service for data
3. The Service retrieves a small amount of data from the 3rd-party and before it returns it...
4. **HERE IT COMES**: the service spawns a background-thread to download a large amount of data from the 3rd-party
5. The service returns the small amount of data
6. The client gets the small amount of data and displays it, but also starts polling the service for the large amount of data
7. The large amount of data is downloaded to the WCF-service, and put into a cache-database
8. The Service returns the large amount of data to the client upon next polling-request.

My questions:

1. Am I not thinking straight about this?
2. What kind of background-threading mechanism should I use? The WCF-service is hosted in IIS.
3. Is polling from the client the right way to retrieve the next chunk of data?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: On #8, it really depends on what your client expects. Is there a filter involve? IF yes then the cached-data may not be valid at the time the filter is changed on the client. So in effect, you will be returning a data set that is not entirely accurate.

Comment: @vonv. I was thinking that the polling-query from the client will include the filtering-data, so the cache will contain all data, and filtering will be done on it before returned.

Comment: It's a good approach then, if the 3rd party is really that slow. But I have to say, it's like you are duplicating the responsibility of the 3rd party. If the data are by millions in count then you would need to save it in a database. So you have the data over at your provider (the 3rd party) and you have a copy at your end, not nice.